# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web Application, Api page not found issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

My Environment Windows 10. Visual Studio 2019 Professional, Asp.Net Core 3.1

I am following a Pluralsight course to teach myself Asp.Net Core 3.1. Following the instructor, I have created the web application. Everything goes well until the instructor adds an api controller to the application. It works for him but not for me.

Here's my api controller

```
namespace OdeToFood.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RestaurantsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly OdeToFoodDbContext _context;

        public RestaurantsController(OdeToFoodDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Restaurants
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Restaurant>>> GetRestaurants()
        {
            return await _context.Restaurants.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Restaurants/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Restaurant>> GetRestaurant(int id)
        {
            var restaurant = await _context.Restaurants.FindAsync(id);

            if (restaurant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return restaurant;
        }

. . . . .
```

Here's my project structure and hierarchy.
[image]

When I rebuild my project, and call the app from local IIS Express, i.e. https://localhost:44351/  It loads fine. I can interact fully, browse and CRUD entities.  However when I point to any api url, e.g. https://localhost:44351/api/Restaurants  or https://localhost:44351/api/Restaurants/2  I get "This localhost page can’t be found".  The api simply does not load or respond in any way.

I am familiar with MVC5 where, when creating a new project, in the create project wizard scaffolding, you could check a box to add api functionality.  I am not seeing this in VS2019 for Asp.Net Core 3.1 We Apps.

I promise you have have done my homework before asking this question here.  I have googled to death. I have seen MS articles on core 3.1 breaking changes. I have looked at online project templates. I have searched stackoverflow.  Maybe my search terms are flawed and I'm simply missing something simple.

**Questions:**

1. Why is the api shown above not loading?
2. Is there a way to add api functionality to an existing Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web Application or do I need to create a separate api project?
3. Is there a way to create a new Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web Application with api functionality included?

My thanks in advance

Kieran

Comment: Just Give a simple try with string return from method,and check if it works or not. I just copied your code and tested with String return it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to add web APIs feature into an existing Razor Pages project, you need to do additional configuration, like below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //add services for controllers
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddRazorPages();

    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseRouting();

    //...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        //add endpoints for controller actions
        endpoints.MapControllers();

        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Testing code of controller and action(s)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RestaurantsController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult GetRestaurants()
    {
        return Ok("Restaurants List Here");
    }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: None of the above works.  Is there a way for me to post my Startup.cs without clicking "answer your own question" ? It includes everything you mention.  Note, the api controller is never hit.  A breakpoint in the constructor is never called.

Comment: I've just discovered that I needed to add a 'endpoints.MapControllers();' line to the app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => lambda.  Now it works.   So in Startup.cs, under Configure, use 
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

Comment: `needed to add a 'endpoints.MapControllers();' line to the app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => lambda. Now it works` Hi @user2026382, if you check my above sample code carefully, you would find that I have pointed that with a comment `'//add endpoints for controller actions'` in example. If the solution did help resolve the problem, you can refer to [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to accept it as answer.